# Почему зависает setInterval во время работы цикла?

Tags: javascript

Зависает setInterval во время работы цикла, примерно на 3 секунды останавливается время, точнее обрывается.

Как выяснилось во время работы цикла как бы зависает полностью страница, в том числе зависает весь js на странице.

Можно ли как то сделать чтобы цикл работал фоном без зависания всей страницы?

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let date = new Date();
  $('.timer').html( date.getMinutes() +':'+ date.getSeconds() );
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Начало цикла');
  for (let i = 0; i <= 1000000000; i++) {
    let j = i + i;
  }
  console.log('Конец цикла');
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Можно. Уберите `setTimeout` с циклом на миллиард итераций.

Comment: @Igor, это чисто для примера, чтобы визуально показать проблему

Comment: Сейчас минус поставлю.

Comment: Я не знаю, как Вам правильно отобразить Ваш пример цикла. Но начинаю подозревать, что Вы выполняете долгий плотный цикл, который и вешает страницу.

Comment: `Можно ли как то сделать чтобы цикл работал фоном без зависания всей страницы?` - Нельзя! Потому, что JS - работает в одном программном потоке, и мультипоточность в нем не реализована. Соответсвенно, невозможно запустить отдельный ТЯЖЕЛЫЙ фоновый поток, чтобы он не мешал основному потоку.

Comment: Цикл работает примерно 2-3 секунды, в это время не работает setInterval. Цикл это чисто для примера чтобы симулировать работу какой либо сложной функции на 2-3 секунды. Как раз проблема в том что во время работы сложной функции не работает setInterval

Comment: @NoSkill, вы меня поняли) есть ли какие то обходные пути?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API